# Visual Studio 2010 C# one-liners compiler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, code-snippets, visual-studio-extensions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Anders Hejlsberg's C# 4.0 REPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1187423/anders-hejlsbergs-c-sharp-4-0-repl)

Is there a native window/extension in VS2010 where you can write one-liners and see the result( like the 'Immediate Window', witch, as far as I know, is only usable in Debug mode).

I'm not interested in external tools like Linq Pad or SnippetCompiler

Comment: I've voted to close as a duplicate because it's a long-standing question whose answer, I believe is still ultimately the same.  Incidentally - the comment from 2011 on the question itself there, pointing to Roslyn, is prescient - because MS are in the process rearchitecting and unifying the whole compilation stack and part of that *could* yield a C# REPL window (I believe Roslyn does include one)

Comment: check out http://stackoverflow.com/a/760475/999042. Anyway, being "not interested" in perfectly functional external tools is illogic.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With Roslyn, Visual Studio will get a built in interactive window:

http://blog.filipekberg.se/2011/11/14/using-the-c-interactive-window-that-comes-with-roslyn/

Unfortunately, it is still only at CTP status.

Comment: +1; also see http://blogs.msdn.com/b/csharpfaq/archive/2012/01/30/roslyn-ctp-introduces-interactive-code-for-c.aspx

Comment: +1 I use this all the time, and it works great for most situations.

Comment: Waw !! I didn't know that, it's a pretty cool stuuff !

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the IronPython interactive console (inside visual studio) could do the work. But it's not a straight answer :/

http://ironpython.net/